# How does javac determine the source dependencies of the current source file?

Tags: java, javac, jls

Consider the following two classes, defined in two source files:

##### Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
}
```

##### Bar.java

```
public class Bar {
  Foo foo;
}
```

When we invoke `javac Bar.java`, the current directory now contains `Foo.class` and `Bar.class`.

I'd like to understand the exact steps that `javac` uses to determine that it needs to compile `Foo.java` when I ask it to compile `Bar.java`.

**Could I get a pointer to the set of classes in the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk) which implement the steps to infer the source files that a given source file depends on?**

I've looked through the Java [compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html), as well as perused the source myself, but have so far been unsuccessful at finding what I seek, probably due to lack of familiarity.

I am continuing to read the source, but asking this question in case someone happens to be much more familiar with the javac source code and knows this already.

Comment: For the person who voted to close, I'm not looking for recommendations. 
I'm looking for a very concrete and objective answer that can be verified to be true or false.

Comment: The JDK source contains a class `ClassFinder` (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/ClassFinder.java) which might be a central point of what you're looking for.